# Need guidance on the prerequisites for migration from SharePoint 2013 to SharePoint online

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, content-migration, sharepoint-alerts

I have a requirement to migrate SP 2013 to SP Online. I want to know the following:

- How do I migrate users
- Do I need to disable alert or SMTP configuration before below migration at source end?
- Will Designer workflows be migrated along with list or library
- Will Nintex workflows be migrated along with list or library
- Will the alerts can be migrated if sharegate tool is used?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are ready to use the SharePoint Migration Tool (SPMT), which is a Microsoft developed migration tool available at no cost to do the migration, Alerts and designer workflows and Nintex workflows are not supported.

You need to recrate them in SharePoint online.

About the user migration, when migrating your data from either a local file share or an on-premises SharePoint Server document library, a default user mapping file is used. You can also create your own using the following guidelines. Use any text editor, or an application like Excel, to create the CSV file.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepointmigration/create-a-user-mapping-file-for-data-content-migration

If you want to use third party tool such as ShareGate, please refer to below articles:

https://sharegate.com/blog/migrate-sharepoint-users-groups-permission-levels

https://support-desktop.sharegate.com/hc/en-us/articles/115000640348-Copy-Structure-Workflows

For professional information about the third party tool, you can ask the third party support for help:

https://support-desktop.sharegate.com/hc/en-us

More information for your reference:

https://infosharepoint.com/all-about-sharepoint-migration-tool-spmt/

Comment: Thanks for the information

Comment: Hi, Do you have the idea on how to get the SPMT Tool to get started with the migration?

Comment: Please refer to https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepointmigration/how-to-use-the-sharepoint-migration-tool

Comment: Is there any option for mapping orphan user at source with a specific user in Microsoft 365 using SPMT?